# mySQL database doesn't respond when the query contains the dot (.) character in Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

When I query the DB through my Android app, I have a problem when the query has a format like:

```
SELECT table1.id FROM table1;
```

If I use the following syntax everything works fine

```
SELECT id FROM table1;
```

I need to specify the table because I use a more complex query from more than 1 tables.

Both queries work fine when I start them directly from phpMyAdmin SQL command window,
but the first one fails from inside my App.

Also if I set directly in PHP

```
$column = "table1.id";
```

and run it from a browser I also have a nice response.

So I believe that there is some kind of problem when I send the String "table1.id" to the php script. I have tried changing my php code like

```
$query = "SELECT ".$column." FROM". $table;
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT {$column} FROM $table";
```

but with no success.
Any ideas?

In java I start a query like this:

```
getQueryResults("table1.id","table1");
```

And this is the php code I use to communicate with my db

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("session.php");

$response = array("success" => 0,"message" => "","data" => "");

if (!empty($_POST)) {

$column = $_POST['column'];
$table = $_POST['table'];

$query = "SELECT $column FROM $table";

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = $ex->getMessage();
    die(json_encode($response));
}

//fetching all the rows from the query
$result= $stmt->fetchAll();
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "We have results!";
$response["data"] = $result;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: this script is just asking for a data leak. maybe do a var_dump on the `$query` variable to make sure it looks like you expect it to.

Comment: `$column = "1; DELETE *";`

Comment: Checking for errors on all sides, will determine why.